# Issue when running from terminal

Tags: sudo, eclipse

I've tried running GParted from the terminal but after requesting for my password nothing happened. Now I'm trying to install Eclipse following the instructions [here](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/04/install-latest-eclipse-ide-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/) but I'm stuck on Step 4. When I type in that code, I get this message:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
** (gedit:21443): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyerror: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
```

This happens to be very similar to what I get when I try to run GParted or even Skype. The command I used was: `sudo gparted` (or skype)

Comment: Please see [Why user should never use normal sudo to start graphical application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application) before you go any further

Comment: @Mr.T It makes sense to run `gparted` [as root](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo), but are you attempting to run `skype` as root?!

Comment: I don't know. In kinda new to this. I just want to use gparted and eclipse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't launch graphical apps from terminal after updating to 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768508/cant-launch-graphical-apps-from-terminal-after-updating-to-15-10)